# Replace lang into route name

Tags: javascript, laravel

Look at my code

```
    data.forEach(element => {
         var url = '{{ route("pl.frontend.article.single", ":id") }}';
        url = url.replace(':id', element.id);
        dataHtml += `<a href="` +url+ `"><figure style="background-image: url(/uploads/article/` +element.cover+ `)"> </figure></a></li>`;
    });
```

It works correctly but I want to repleace pl to en, pl, de, etc depending on which language was chosen. This method (with reaplace) doesn't work. Any idea?

@Edit
Look at this:

```
var url = '{{ route(":lang.frontend.article.single", ":id") }}';
```

Laravel display error that route ":lang.frontend.article.single" is not defined. How can I replace lang with other way?

@edit2

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'pl'], function(){
    App::setLocale('pl');
    Auth::routes();
//...
    Route::get('artykul/{id}', [
        'uses' => 'FrontarticlesController@single',
        'as' => 'pl.frontend.article.single'
    ]);
//...

    //and
Route::group(['prefix' => 'en'], function(){
    App::setLocale('en');
    Auth::routes();
    Route::get('article/{id}', [
        'uses' => 'FrontarticlesController@single',
        'as' => 'en.frontend.article.single'
    ]);
```

I translate url so I can't replace url address.

Comment: What do you mean "doesn't work?" This code does the replacement. Is there another problem? Does `:id` exist in the `url` string?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use like this

```
data.forEach(element => {
     var url = "{{url('')}}/artykul/"+id+'/'+lang,
     url = url.replace(':id', element.id);
     dataHtml += `<a href="` +url+ `"><figure style="background-image: url(/uploads/article/` +element.cover+ `)"> </figure></a></li>`;
});
```

And your route like this

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'pl'], function(){
    App::setLocale('pl');
    Auth::routes();
//...
    Route::get('artykul/{id}', [
        'uses' => 'FrontarticlesController@single',
        'as' => 'pl.frontend.article.single'
    ]);
//...

    //and
Route::group(['prefix' => 'en'], function(){
    App::setLocale('en');
    Auth::routes();
    Route::get('articles/{id}', [
        'uses' => 'FrontarticlesController@single',
        'as' => 'en.frontend.article.single'
    ]);
```

Comment: Isn't `{{ ... }}` special Laravel pre-processing? Not sure that'll work with dynamic elements like that in JavaScript.

Comment: @tadman he wants to use lang as variable. Even though it is better to use `id` as variable `lang`

Comment: I tryed that. I have an error `Route ['+ lang +'.frontend.article.single] not defined `. Of course I created lang var;

Comment: You have to change your `url route`

Comment: You have to change your `url route`. And please share your `route`

Comment: Try `var lang = {{ App::getLocale() }};` before the `var url =` bit

Comment: Off question : In output, what is the differences between `"{{ url('')}}/artykul/"` and `"/artykul/"`? @A.A Noman

Comment: @TalhaF. mainly same. But `"{{ url('')}}/artykul/"` means `localhost/project_name/artykul`. It is an another way to call

Comment: It's not that. My url look like this localhost:8000/pl/artykul/1 for example I have a group with pl or en prefix. I updated my code